# Rigidbody2D: How do I prevent the Y axis from being overwritten with 0?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, velocity, gravity

```
public void MoveCharacter(float directionHori) //either -1 or 1
{      
    direction = new Vector2 (directionHori, 0); //new vector2 using passed x value (1 or -1). //BUG - passing in 0 as Y axis overrides gravity while player is moving.

    rb.MovePosition(rb.position + direction * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime); //apply movement 
}
```

Above is my MoveCharacter method, and when it is called, the Y axis is overwritten with 0 therefore gravity is disabled, allowing the player to fly when he's supposed to fall. This is a 2D sidescroller, therefore the player should not be able to move vertically (except when falling of course). I've tried direction = new Vector2 (directionHori, rb.Velocity.y); //replacing 0 with rb.Velocity

however that creates weirder behavior. Any help would be appreciated, I'm still new to Unity! Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using [`MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html) where you would need to calculate the final position yourself you could rather simply adjust the [`velocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D-velocity.html) like

```
var velocity = rb.velocity;
velocity.x = direction * moveSpeed;
rb.velocity = velocity;
```

this keeps the gravity and vertical movement untouched and the `Rigidbody2D` / the physics engine does the calculation for you ;)

Comment: Thank you very much! Really appreciate it.